# Manually selecting which of three ethernet output ports should transmit signal from a single ethernet input, using MCU and transistors?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, ethernet, switching

I have a TV-bench containing three different computer units that all use Ethernet. Although, I only have one measly ethernet output coming out of the wall closest to the bench. Not wanting to clutter my apartment with long ethernet cords, I thought that maybe I could make an MCU powered switching system that allows me to manually switch which unit should use the ethernet by the push of a button.

My idea is as follows:

1. Select ethernet output with pushbutton that corresponds ethernet output port 1 - 3.
2. MCU sends signal to each base of the transistors connected to the desired output port.
3. Continuous signal established between input port and selected output port.

[image: Simplified model of MCU based ethernet switching system, more transistors would be used for each port of course. Dotted line represents output port 2.]

*I realise that I may be using the transistors wrong, but I'm just curious if my idea would even work, so don't hate lol*

My main concern is whether or not you can create paths between ethernet ports this way. I've read [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233969/raspberry-pi-controlled-power-on-off-switching-of-an-ethernet-connection?rq=1#) which sort of touches the topic, but I'm not completely sure me and the OP of said post want to achieve the same thing.

Comment: every  answer to the post you link to says: "Sorry, won't work, can't just switch ethernet with transistors like that". So, to your post: "Sorry, won't work, can't just switch ethernet with transistors like that"

Comment: also, there's a simple solution to your problem, it's called "ethernet switch", (doesn't actually switch, but is more like a telephone exchange for ethernet packets,) is a commodity device that costs <20€ and works reliably, PLUS you can use both devices simultaneousl.y

Comment: Why don't you buy an ethernet switch?

Comment: @user253751 done it.