# Designing an Ethernet / RJ 45 disconnector

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, eaglecad, rj45

I am currently in need of a device that is plugged in between a host and a client to cut the connection regularly on a hardware level.
This should simulate unplugging the Ethernet cable and plugging it back in.
I found something in the right direction as seen here:

[image]

However, I don't want the switch to be toggled manually but rather by an external source such as an Raspberry Pi GPIO.

As I'm not a professional electronical engineer my questions are as follows:

What kind of component do I need? Are there relays that can handle this? If there are, what relays should I look for?

Maybe there are dedicated ICs for this kind of job? Where do I search for them and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that? Can you lead me in the right direction regarding the resources on Ethernet interfaces?

Comment: Will your end device use Power over Ethernet? If so, the power voltages may reach ~50V. Your switching device might need to tolerate these. Also, if any of the devices (including your Pi) are ever powered from different AC phases (outlets?), there might be a large ground difference.

Comment: @awky No PoE. The devices will be powered from different outlets, yes.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate - we covered this before at [How can I make a device that will remotely disconnect an Ethernet port?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21550/how-can-i-make-a-device-that-will-remotely-disconnect-an-ethernet-port)  Also important to keep in mind that searches for parts and questions on the usage of computer/networking gear are off topic.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?